# Is there an alternate way to start vibration in Android?

Tags: android, vibration

Sorry if this question is kind of bad, but a user reported that the vibration in my app isn't working on his Samsung Galaxy S3.
Has anyone ever had an issue with that phone model?

I'm using the standard code for vibration:

```
Vibrator vibe = (Vibrator) getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
vibe.vibrate(1000);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just tried it is working on my S3. android version is 4.1.2,

*PS: this question might not help for future purposes, it might be get closed.*

Comment: His user could be using a battery saving application. Some of those apps turn off all haptic feedback.